# Comparison of two lists: "List index out of range"

Tags: python

I have the following lists:

```
first_list = [25.26, 1.74, 6.07, 7.38, 1.58, 0.71, 0.49, 0.71, 3.94]
second_list = [28.15, 1.28, 7.31, 8.58, 2.09, 0.21, 0.43, 0.83, 4.39]
```

And the following function

```
for num in range(0,9):
    list_one_score = 0
    list_two_score = 0
    if first_list[num] > second_list[num]:
        list_one_score += 1
    else:
        list_two_score += 1
```

each time I run this code I get "IndexError: list index out of range" and I don't understand why. Please help.

Comment: Tried that, still getting the same error :(

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but are you sure you want to reset `list_xxx_score` to 0 at each iteration?

Comment: don't use `else` in for loop. example : `elif first_list[num] <= second_list[num]:` and `list_one_score = 0
    list_two_score = 0` your result a temp value, remove to outside...

Comment: lol , yea, I missed one.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your loop

```
for item_one, item_two in zip(first_list, second_list):
    if item_one > item_two:
        list_one_score += 1
    else:
        list_two_score += 1
```

That will take your two lists, pair them together, and iterate over the result. This will stop you from getting your `IndexError`.

Is your example the exact same thing as what you're running locally ?

Comment: Thanks Christian, I've created a new program with exactly the code I've entered above and tried your solution and it's worked. It hasn't worked in my main program, but that must be to some other conflict.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code, Range is Proper.

```
first_list = [25.26, 1.74, 6.07, 7.38, 1.58, 0.71, 0.49, 0.71, 3.94]
second_list = [28.15, 1.28, 7.31, 8.58, 2.09, 0.21, 0.43, 0.83, 4.39]

list_one_score = 0
list_two_score = 0

for num in range(0,9):
    if first_list[num] > second_list[num]:
        list_one_score += 1
    else:
        list_two_score += 1
print(list_one_score)
print(list_two_score)

#Or Remove the Index only by this logic
for a,b in in zip(first_list, second_list):
    if a > b:
        list_one_score += 1
    else:
        list_two_score += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you get IndexError

```
'''
list_number.py
'''

#declare variables
first_list = [25.26, 1.74, 6.07, 7.38, 1.58, 0.71, 0.49, 0.71, 3.94]
second_list = [28.15, 1.28, 7.31, 8.58, 2.09, 0.21, 0.43, 0.83, 4.39]
list_one_score = 0
list_two_score = 0

#loop
for num in range(0,9):
    if first_list[num] > second_list[num]:
        list_one_score += 1
    else:
        list_two_score += 1

#Print
print '''
score list 1 = %d
score list 2 = %d
''' % (list_one_score, list_two_score)
```